# uniqueidentifier is incompatible with newid()

Tags: c#

```cs
string insert =@"INSERT INTO SysUser (UserId, UserPw, FullName, Email, CorporateId, UserRole, Active, ActivationToken) 
VALUES ('{0}', HASHBYTES('SHA1', '{1}'), '{2}', '{3}', {4}, 'user',0, NEWID() )";

if (DBUtl.ExecSQL(insert, usr.UserId, usr.UserPw, usr.FullName, usr.Email, usr.CorporateId) == 1)
{
  usr.ActivationToken = Guid.NewGuid();
  string baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}", HttpContext.Request.Scheme, HttpContext.Request.Host);

   ...
}
```

I stored ActivationToken as uniqueidentifier data type in my database however after i execute, it says

> Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

suggesting that newid() is a int datatype? What is the correct data type to insert guid in 'ActivationToken'? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: First of all, you should not add parameter values with string concatenation or `string.Format` but use parameterized queries. Second, no it's not suggesting that `NEWID()` returns an `int`, but that at least one column where you try to insert a unique identifier expects an int.

Comment: But as we neither know your table definition, nor your data, nor what `DBUtl.ExecSQL` does, nobody say, where the problem is.

Comment: Even if this code worked as-is, it seems quite improbable that you want the database to generate the activation token for you (`NEWID()`) and then discard this information and generate a new token yourself (`usr.ActivationToken = Guid.NewGuid()`). Either generate it client-side and store it, or have the database generate it and retrieve it, but not both. Furthermore, you are transmitting a password in plaintext to the database and asking it to hash the bytes for you, which is not as secure (or repeatable, given that the encoding is determined by collation) as hashing it client-side.

Comment: Furthermore, you are inserting `newid()` as activationtoken in your database, but assigning `usr.ActivationToken = Guid.NewGuid()` later on in your model. These two guids will be different, so probably your activation check won't work.

Comment: @JeroenMostert If one is hashing passwords with SHA1, it doesn't really matter, where the hashing happens. It's insecure anyways.

Comment: @derpirscher: yes, SHA-1 ought not to be used anymore. My remark remains relevant if the hashing algorithm is replaced by one which is still considered secure (the current scheme involves no salt either); transmitting the password in the plain is a separate security problem.

Comment: Thank you for both your input, very useful, I amended my database and now it worked. Now I am trying to authenticate the activationtoken in the controller/action that I passed my link to with the activationtoken I generated in database so I can set my active = 1. (reasoning behind this is to activate account only if user has clicked on the link). Is there a way to retrieve link of the said controller/action?